# XSLT: why /*/* overrides /*/x and * doesn't ovverides x?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to understand the differences between the following two examples. I don't understand why in the first case x is matched with the `match="x"` template, while in the second case, the X element is matched by `/*/*` and not by `/*/x`. Here's the code:

First example, input file:

```
<a> <c> <a> 
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
</a>
    <f><b>3</b>
    </f>
</c>
    <b> <c>4</c> 5 </b>
</a>
```

First example, XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="a">
        <A><xsl:apply-templates/></A> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="b"> 
        <B><xsl:value-of select="."/></B>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="c"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*"> 
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Second example, input file:

```
<a>
<x>testo 0
    <rad>testo 1</rad>
</x>
<b>
    <p>
        <w>
            <z>testo 2</z>
        </w>
    </p>
</b>
<y>
    <p/>
    <y>testo 3
        <d>testo 4</d>
    </y>
</y>
<f/>
```

Second example, XSLT:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:element name="r">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/x">
        <nx><xsl:element name="oldx"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/></nx>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/y">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <new>
            <xsl:element name="{name()}"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </new>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of the second file should be the following one, and I can get it only applying the condition `[name()!='x' and name()!='y']` to the `/* /*` match template. If I don't apply this condition, when the X element is found in the input file, the XSLT file apply the `/* /*` template and not the `/* /x` template, as it happens in the first example. Which is the difference between the two examples?
Thank you!

Output expected for the second example:

```
<r>
<nx>
<oldx/>
<new>
<rad/>
</new>
</nx>
<b>
<new>
<p/>
</new>
</b>
<new>
<p/>
</new>
<new>
<y/>
</new>
<f/>
</r>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict explains the rules for resolving template matches when more than one is a possible choice. They're simpler than you might expect.

In many cases, it's going to be your responsibility to either explicitly use the `priority=` attribute to help clarify which template takes precedence, or to use [modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes) to select which set of templates is active at any given time, or to rewrite your stylesheet so the matches are more explicit and don't collide with each other.

Comment: Hi, I've read the document you linked, but again, I don't understand the difference between the two example. According to the table. * has priority -0.5 and element X 0.0. So in the first case match=X has an higher priority and is appyed. In the second case, according to the table / has priority -0.5. So, /* /* should have priority -2, /* /* should have prioriy -1.5, which is higher, but /* /* is applyed... What's wrong?

Comment: Priorities are not summed. Priorities are set by which XSLT grammar production they match.

`/*/*` and `/*/x` both match the production [PathPattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#NT-PathPattern). That puts them in the "otherwise" case for the priority rules, giving them priority 0.5. `x`, on the other hand, is an [NCName](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-NCName), and has priority -0.25.

Comment: I'm not sure a long table of patterns, priorities, and rationalles would be considered in scope for StackOverflow. That's the sort of thing you'd normally expect to find in a tutorial, not a quick Q-and-A.